# Django Form Displaying Form Error on GET Method

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been using django web framework for some time now, I would love to write a custom password change form without using the default provided by django or third-party packages.

I have tried following a similar pattern used in django [SetPasswordForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45ecd9acca9b36093e274f47b6877a5f79108d9e/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L372) and [PasswordChangeForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45ecd9acca9b36093e274f47b6877a5f79108d9e/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L416)

### My Current Implementation

**project/app/forms.py**

```py
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    old_password = forms.CharField(max_length=50, )
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50, )
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=50, )

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        old_password = cleaned_data.get('old_password')
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')
        # Validate new user password

        if password1 and password2 and old_password:
            if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
                raise ValidationError("Invalid old password, please enter your current password")
            elif password1 != password2:
                raise ValidationError("Password mismatch, please re-type same password")
        password_validation.validate_password(password1, self.user)
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        new_password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        self.user.set_password(new_password)
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

**project/app/views.py**

```py
class ChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.user, request.POST)
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'auth/change_password.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # log user out of all active sessions
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Password updated successfully")
            return redirect('custom_redirect')
        return redirect('custom_redirect')
```

**HTML Template Rendering**

```
 <form class="card-style mb-30" action="{% url 'account_change_password' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <h6 class="mb-25">Change Password</h6>

   {% if form.errors %}
   <div class="text-sm mb-25 alert alert-danger "> <i class="lni lni-close"></i>
     <span>{{form.errors}}</span>
   </div>

   {% for field in form %}
   {% for error in field.errors %}

   <div class="text-sm mb-25 alert alert-danger "> <i class="lni lni-close"></i>
     <span>{{error|escape}}</span>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}

   {% if form.non_field_errors %}
   <div class="text-sm mb-25 alert alert-danger "> <i class="lni lni-close"></i>
     <span>{{form.non_field_errors}}ghgh </span>
   </div>
   {% endif %}


   <div class="input-style-3">
     <input type="password" placeholder="Enter old password" name="old_password" required>
     <span class="icon"><i class="lni lni-key"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="input-style-3">
     <input type="password" placeholder="Enter new password" name="password1" required>
     <span class="icon"><i class="lni lni-key"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="input-style-3">
     <input type="password" placeholder="Enter new password again" name="password2" required>
     <span class="icon"><i class="lni lni-key"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
     <div class="button-group d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
       <button type="submit" type="submit" class="main-btn primary-btn btn-hover m-2">
         Change Password
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

The major problem I am facing is the the form validation get invoked on GET method, after trying random attempts to fix this problem, I realized that this problem was as a result of how I called the Superclass __init __ method. Each time I remove the line `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`  I get an error message that says **'ChangePasswordForm' object has no attribute '_errors'**

Please note that I have been rendering form to django template using the pattern in the above sample and haven't had any problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **get()** method you have no form data, So remove **request.POST** from get() method and handle error in **post()** method.

```
class ChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.user)
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'auth/change_password.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            context = {
                'form': form,
            }
            return render(request, 'auth/change_password.html', context)
            
        user = form.save()
        # log user out of all active sessions
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Password updated successfully")
        return redirect(reverse('custom_redirect'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `return redirect('custom_redirect'))`  with  `return redirect('custom_redirect')`